# Wordpress select setting in customizer not outputing proper code

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a customizer section inside my wordpress theme. I made a setting and a control for an icon. I want my user to be able to choose what icon he wants. I implemented the icomoon icon font with classes like icon-home.

I made a setting and a control for that icon like this:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'service1_icon',
    array(
        'default' => 'icon1',
        'type' => 'option',
    )
);

$wp_customize->add_control(
    'service1_icon',
    array(
        'label' => 'Service 1 Icon',
        'section' => 'section_services',
        'type' => 'select',
        'choices' => array(
            'icon1' => 'mobile',
            'icon2' => 'home',
        ),
    )
);
```

and in html/php:

```
<span class="service-icon icon-<?php echo get_theme_mod('service1_icon', 'icon1'); ?>"></span>
```

But when in my browser I see the output like this:

```
<span class="service-icon icon-icon1"></span>
```

instead of:

```
<span class="service-icon icon-mobile"></span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to fix it and did some stuff that were illogical to me and I fixed it.

First, I removed the type from the setting:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'service1_icon',
    array(
        'default' => 'icon1',
    )
);
```

Then I renamed icon1, icon2... to the actual name of the icon:

```
$wp_customize->add_control(
    'service1_icon',
    array(
        'label' => 'Service 1 Icon',
        'section' => 'section_services',
        'type' => 'select',
        'choices' => array(
            'mobile' => 'mobile',
            'home' => 'home',
        ),
    )
);
```